# Problema cuando el teléfono esta bloqueado

Tags: android, android-studio

Intento lanzar un activity cuando el teléfono esta bloqueado y veo que se lanza muchas veces seguidas, pero cuando se lanza con la pantalla encendida funciona normal, tengo api 23, probé con apis anteriores y esto no sucede ¿Que debo hacer para que Start Activity se lance una sola vez sin importar que el teléfono este bloqueado?

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, MapsActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(dialogIntent);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //escritor="4";
        Bander2="2";
        SharedPreferences contra = getSharedPreferences("", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = contra.edit();
        editor1.putString("Contraseña", String.valueOf(ACTIVO));
        editor1.commit();
        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDistance);
        text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        SharedPreferences cedula = getSharedPreferences("", MODE_PRIVATE);
        ced = cedula.getString("Usuario", "");
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.to);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        spref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonFollow);
        on = spref.getBoolean("On", true);  //default is true
        if (on == true) {
            tb.setChecked(true);
            tb.setBackgroundColor(0xffcc0000);
        } else {
            tb.setChecked(false);
            tb.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        notificacion = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            AlertNoGps();
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            } else {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }
        } else {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
        MostrarLocalizacion(location);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                MostrarLocalizacion(location);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        };

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListener);}
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListener);
        }
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }
public void carrera(int id, int iconid, String titulo, String contenido) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MapsActivity.this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(iconid)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.mipmap.poder_amarillo))
                    .setContentTitle(titulo)
                    .setContentIntent(contIntent)
                    .setSound((Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.vip)))
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{ 1000,500,1000,800,1000,1500 })
                    .setLights(Color.RED,3000,3000)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setContentText(contenido);
    notificacion.notify(id, builder.build());
}

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {

    on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
    if (on) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("On", true); // value to store
        editor.commit();
        tb.setBackgroundColor(0xffcc0000);
        escritor = "4";
        resp = "2";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Su estado ha cambiado a ocupado!!!" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        send();
    } else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("On", false); // value to store
        editor.commit();
        text2.setText(null);
        text3.setText(null);
        text1.setText(null);
        resp = "0";
        tb.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        escritor = "4";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Su estado ha cambiado a disponible!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mMap.clear();
        X = "0";
        Y = "0";
        send();
    }
}
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void  send (){
    hiloconexion = new obtenerwebservice();
    hiloconexion.execute(String.valueOf(escritor),String.valueOf(ced),String.valueOf(ACTIVO),String.valueOf(lat),String.valueOf(lon),String.valueOf(resp),String.valueOf(TIME));
}

private void sendRequest() {
    String origin = String.valueOf(lat)+","+String.valueOf(lon);   
    String destination = Y+","+X;

    try {
        new DirectionFinder(this, origin, destination).execute();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDirectionFinderStart() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Espere por favor",
            "Obteniendo ruta!", true);

    if (originMarkers != null) {
        for (Marker marker : originMarkers) {
            marker.remove();
        }
    }

    if (destinationMarkers != null) {
        for (Marker marker : destinationMarkers) {
            marker.remove();
        }
    }

    if (polylinePaths != null) {
        for (Polyline polyline:polylinePaths ) {
            polyline.remove();
        }
    }
}
    public void MostrarLocalizacion(Location loc) {
        if(ACTIVO == "0"){
            loc = null;
        }
        if (loc != null) {
            hiloconexion = new obtenerwebservice();       hiloconexion.execute(String.valueOf(escritor),String.valueOf(ced),String.valueOf(ACTIVO),String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()),String.valueOf(resp),String.valueOf(TIME));
        }
    }
    public void servicio() {
        hiloconexion = new obtenerwebservice();
        hiloconexion.execute("2", String.valueOf(ced), String.valueOf(ACTIVO), String.valueOf(lat), String.valueOf(lon), String.valueOf(resp), String.valueOf(TIME));
    }
@Override
public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Route route : routes) {
        text2.setText(route.distance.text);
        text3.setText(route.duration.text);
        TIME = text3.getText().toString();
        send();
        /*originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.poder_amarillo))
                .title(route.startAddress)
                .position(route.startLocation)));*/
        destinationMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.poder_amarillo))
                .title(route.endAddress)
                .position(route.endLocation)));

        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                geodesic(true).
                color(Color.BLUE).
                width(8);

        for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++)
            polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));

        polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));
    }
}
public void alertcar(){
    Bander = "0";
    builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Dirección: " + comentario +" ¿Desea aceptar el servicio?")
            .setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("SI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            text1.setText(comentario);
            resp="4";
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("On", true); // value to store
            editor.commit();
            tb.setChecked(true);
            tb.setText("ocupado");
            tb.setBackgroundColor(0xffcc0000);
            escritor = "4";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Su estado ha cambiado a ocupado!!!" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Bander = "1";
            notificacion.cancelAll();
            sendRequest();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            text1.setText(null);
            resp="3";
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("On", true); // value to store
            editor.commit();
            tb.setChecked(true);
            tb.setText("ocupado");
            tb.setBackgroundColor(0xffcc0000);
            escritor = "4";
            Bander = "1";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Su estado ha cambiado a ocupado!!!" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mMap.clear();
            X = "0";
            Y = "0";
            notificacion.cancelAll();
            send();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
    public void Exit  (){
        ACTIVO="0";
        SharedPreferences contra = getSharedPreferences("",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = contra.edit();
        editor1.putString("Contraseña",String.valueOf(ACTIVO));
        editor1.commit();
        hiloconexion = new obtenerwebservice();
   hiloconexion.execute(String.valueOf(escritor),String.valueOf(ced),String.valueOf(ACTIVO),"0","0",String.valueOf(resp));
        servicio();
    }
  private ProgressDialog pDialog;
public void Zaliendo(){

    builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("¿Desea salir de la aplicación?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("SI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Exit();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Desconectando del servidor...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK) {
     Zaliendo();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
public class obtenerwebservice extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            int devuelve =0;
            URL url = null;
            String cade = "http://186.183.210.220/actualizar_alumno.php";
            String cadena ="http://186.183.210.220/obtener_alumno_por_id.php?username="+ced;
            String caden = "http://186.183.210.220/myservice.php";
            while (Bander2 == "2") {
                if (params[0] == "4") {
                    try {
                        HttpURLConnection urlConn;
                        DataOutputStream printout;
                        DataInputStream input;
                        url = new URL(cade);
                        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        urlConn.setDoInput(true);
                        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
                        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
                        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                        urlConn.connect();
                        //Creo el Objeto JSON
                        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                        jsonParam.put("username", params[1]);
                        jsonParam.put("activo", params[2]);
                        jsonParam.put("latitud", params[3]);
                        jsonParam.put("longitud", params[4]);
                        jsonParam.put("servicio", params[5]);
                        jsonParam.put("tiempo", params[6]);
                        // Envio los parámetros post.
                        OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream();
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                        writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
                        writer.flush();
                        writer.close();
                        int respuesta = urlConn.getResponseCode();
                        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                        if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                            String line;
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
                            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                result.append(line);
                                //response+=line;
                            }
                            //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                            JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                            //Accedemos al vector de resultados
                            int resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getInt("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON
                            if (resultJSON == 1) {
                                devuelve = 4;
                            } else if (resultJSON == 2) {
                                devuelve = 4;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    escritor = "3";
                    return String.valueOf(devuelve);


                } else if (params[0] == "2") {    // consulta por id
                    try {
                        url = new URL(cadena);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //Abrir la conexión
                        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" +
                                " (Linux; Android 1.5; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP");
                        //connection.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                        int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode();
                        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                        if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());  // preparo la cadena de entrada
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  // la introduzco en un BufferedReader
                            // El siguiente proceso lo hago porque el JSONOBject necesita un String y tengo
                            // que tranformar el BufferedReader a String. Esto lo hago a traves de un
                            // StringBuilder.
                            String line;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                result.append(line);        // Paso toda la entrada al StringBuilder
                            }
                            //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                            JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                            //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                            int resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getInt("estado");
                            if (resultJSON == 1) {      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                                devuelve = respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("users").getInt("servicio");
                                Z = respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("users").getInt("latitud");
                                Log.i("mensaje", String.valueOf(Z));
                                if (Prim == 1) {
                                    if (Z == 0) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Login.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                        System.exit(0);
                                    }
                                }
                                Prim = 1;
                                if (devuelve == 1) {
                                    Y = respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("users").getString("lat");
                                    X = respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("users").getString("lon");
                                    comentario = respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("users").getString("comentario");
                                }
                            } else if (resultJSON == 2) {
                                devuelve = 2;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return String.valueOf(devuelve);

                } else if (params[0] == "3") {
                    try {
                        HttpURLConnection urlConn;
                        DataOutputStream printout;
                        DataInputStream input;
                        url = new URL(caden);
                        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        urlConn.setDoInput(true);
                        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
                        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
                        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                        urlConn.connect();
                        //Creo el Objeto JSON
                        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                        jsonParam.put("username", params[1]);
                        jsonParam.put("activo", params[2]);
                        jsonParam.put("latitud", params[3]);
                        jsonParam.put("longitud", params[4]);
                        // Envio los parámetros post.
                        OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream();
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                        writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
                        writer.flush();
                        writer.close();
                        int respuesta = urlConn.getResponseCode();
                        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                        if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                            String line;
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
                            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                result.append(line);
                            }
                            //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                            JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   

                            int resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getInt("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON
                            if (resultJSON == 1) {
                                devuelve = 4;
                            } else if (resultJSON == 2) {
                                devuelve = 4;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    servicio();
                    return String.valueOf(devuelve);
                }
            }
                return "5";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(String aVoid) {
            super.onCancelled(aVoid);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            int numero = 0;
            numero = Integer.parseInt(aVoid);
            if (1 == numero) {
                if (escritor == "3"){
                    if (Bander=="1"){
                        carrera(1,R.mipmap.poder_amarillo,"Taxis VIP","Actualmente tiene un servicio");
                        alertcar();}
                }

            }else if ( numero == 4){

                Log.i("GPSactivi", aVoid);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Envio del Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Destruida" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //notificacion.cancelAll();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pausa" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bander ="1";
        stopService(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MyService.class));
        this.mWakeLock.acquire();
        Bander2 ="2";
        servicio();
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Comment: Agrega el metodo completo que realiza este startActivity().

Comment: Perdón te envió el código después del start espero me puedas ayudar y corregir en lo que puedas.

Comment: Que actividad se esta abriendo varias veces?

Comment: El startActivity hace que se inicie esta parte del código, cuando esta en uso el celular funciona muy bien, pero cuando el celular esta bloqueado con la pantalla apagada lo intenta lanzar pero se cierra y hace esto ciclicamente.